# Need help in my makefile to compile a source code

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have 2 folders with their subfolders 04-Software Components / 03-Specific_sources and 08-Ext_Proj / SWC_ADC, SWC_PWM / 03-SRC

There are some .c and .h files in 03-Specific_sources and there is one .c file and their .h
files in both SWC_ADC / 03-SRC (which is ADC.c) and 
SWC_PWM / 03-SRC (which is PWM.c)

And I want to compile them and link them all to get the output file.
so what I did is this:

```
EXEDIR_RELEASE := ../01-EXE\02-Release
OBJDIR_RELEASE := ../05-Obj\02-Release
SRCDIR := ../../../03-Specific_sources (This is the path from my make folder)

EXT_DIR  := ../../08-Ext_Proj (This is the path from my make folder)
FIND_SRCS := $(wildcard $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_*/03-SRC/*.c)

INCLUDES := -I $(SRCDIR) $(foreach ext, $(wildcard $(EXT_DIR)/SWC*), -I $(ext)/03-SRC)

CSRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) $(FIND_SRCS)
CSRCS := $(notdir $(CSRCS))

CROBJS := $(patsubst %.c, %.r34, $(CSRCS))
CROBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/, $(CROBJS))

.PHONY: all 

all: $(EXEDIR_RELEASE)/$(TARGET_RELEASE)

# Compiling
$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/%.r34: $(FIND_SRCS)
        @echo '$^ $@'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $<

# Linking
$(EXEDIR_RELEASE)/Target.mot: $(CROBJS)
    $(LD) $(MFLAGS) # These are the linker and its flags
```

The problem is that the compilation is not working. So when I do the echo I get this:

```
ADC_prg.c PWM_prg.c DDF_prg.r34
ADC_prg.c PWM_prg.c DFAN_prg.r34
ADC_prg.c PWM_prg.c DFN_prg.r34
ADC_prg.c PWM_prg.c DIO_prg.r34
ADC_prg.c PWM_prg.c DMIO_prg.r34
```

So I think that the mathing pattern %.r34 is not working and when I use
($(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/%.r34: $(FIND_SRCS)/%.c) it also not working because I can't use %
with a variable that has wildcard function performed on it.

I also used the foreach function but with no use.

So please I need your help guys, I have a delivery today... please respond asap.

Thanks in advance
SAM

Comment: As your question stands, it is unclear what you are asking.  Please see the FAQ @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before editing your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This makefile has a lot of problems. Notably:

```
$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/%.r34: $(FIND_SRCS)
    @echo '$^ $@'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $<
```

This pattern rule has no wildcard ("%") in the prerequisite list. *Any* r34 target depends on *all* sources in `$(FIND_SRCS)`. If that isn't bad enough, look at where these variables come from:

```
SRCDIR := ../../../03-Specific_sources (This is the path from my make folder)

EXT_DIR  := ../../08-Ext_Proj (This is the path from my make folder)
FIND_SRCS := $(wildcard $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_*/03-SRC/*.c)

...

CSRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) $(FIND_SRCS)
CSRCS := $(notdir $(CSRCS))

CROBJS := $(patsubst %.c, %.r34, $(CSRCS))
CROBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/, $(CROBJS))
```

In other words, you seem to expect that for every source file in one directory there will be a file of the same name in the other directory. According to your `echo` statements, there are *no* such matches.

There are other problems, but this is a good place to start. Try this:

```
CSRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_ADC/03-SRC/ADC.c $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_PWM/03-SRC/PWM.c
CSRCS := $(notdir $(CSRCS))
CROBJS := $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/%.r34, $(CSRCS))

vpath %.c $(SRCDIR) $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_ADC/03-SRC $(EXT_DIR)/SWC_PWM/03-SRC

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/%.r34: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $<
```

Go down the list of object files you want to build, and try building each one:

```
make DDF_prg.r34
make DFAN_prg.r34
...
```

If that works, try linking them *by hand*, and if that works, take a look at the linking rule -- which looks completely wrong but which I can't really diagnose because I don't know what linker you're using.